# How Can I Detect Ellipses in OpenCV/JavaCV?

Tags: object, opencv, detection, javacv, ellipse

I am currently working on a program to detect coordinates of pool balls in an image of a pool table taken from an arbitrary point.

I first calculated the table corners and warped the perspective of the image to obtain a bird's eye view. Unfortunately, this made the spherical balls appear to be slightly elliptical as shown below.

[image]

**In an attempt to detect the ellipses, I extracted all but the green felt area and used a Hough transform algorithm (HoughCircles) on the resulting image shown below. Unfortunately, none of the ellipses were detected (I can only assume because they are not circles).**

[image]

### Is there any better method of detecting the balls in this image? I am technically using JavaCV, but OpenCV solutions should be suitable. Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extracted BW image is good but it needs some morphological filters to eliminate noises then you can extract external contours of each object (by cvFindContours) and fit best ellipse to them (by cvFitEllipse2).